# Edit Site List not under JAVA > Security

Tags: java

I need to add some URL in the Exception Site List under ‘Edit Site List’. But I do not found it on my Start > Control Panel > JAVA > Security.

[image]

Comment: @Himanshu Code back-ticks should not be used to highlight arbitrary words in a post. I would have rejected that edit if I'd seen it myself.

Comment: Please enter your code

Comment: This appears to be a question about configuring a software tool (your Java runtime). As a result, I've voted to close this as off topic, since it doesn't contain a programming question.

Comment: cool.. As you do not know the answer you closed the topic I guess :)..  anyways thanks !

Comment: It is not important if we do or don't know the answer. In the [Help] is stated what is on-topic here and I also don't see yet how this is uniquely to software development. How ever [this](http://java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml) makes me wonder if you're using a java version before v7.0 update 51...

Comment: I understand. but to answer your question.. I had previous version of update 45 before this 51 update..

Comment: FWIW, I am having this same problem: I upgraded to u51, and now I need to add some exception sites (which I didn't before) -- and it's not showing up in the list.

Comment: As far as the off-topic-ness, it's a tough call.  Certainly this is not EXACTLY a programming question... but it's a fair bet that a high fraction of the people needing to do this are developers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just solved this problem by uninstalling older versions of Java from the Control Panel.

```
Control Panel > Uninstall a Program
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Java to version 1.8, it shows the "Edit Site" list in the Security tab.